# How to render point cloud with colors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, point-clouds

There are some topics about this question but I need more detail to implement. I use a depth camera and a color camera of a Tango to obtain point cloud with color which is extracted from an image or an byte array. To achieve this, I do as follows:

1. I get point cloud using a `TangoPointCloudAvailable` callback. Similarly, a color image (or a byte array) is obtained using a `TangoImageAvailable` callback.
2. I align the depth camera and the color camera using the color camera's intrinsics. To implement this, I activate a "*Tango AR Screen*" script in the Tango Camera object. The reason for this is that there is a one-to-one relationship between a color in a color image and a point cloud.
3. I manually synchronize time stamps of depth and color cameras. To do this, I store all color images with their time stamps using a dictionary. When point cloud is available, I loop through all time stamps of color images and find a time stamp that has the smallest difference with the point cloud's time stamp.
4. For each point in the point cloud, I extract a corresponding color from the color image and convert from the YUV format to the RGB format.

When I run a program on a Tango, it is very slow and the color of point cloud is incorrect. Is there anyone experienced this problem?